# Adding an external API to Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new with this Laravel stuff and an API too (Never done this before), but i know PHP and Javascript. But I want to learn these stuffs ASAP, so sorry if my questions are dumb :D

So what I want to ask you guys are:

1. Is that possible to add an External API to Laravel 5.2? and where do i need to put it?

> Because some people said that you can't add an External API to Laravel.

2. How to apply this API to Laravel (If it's possible)?

> ```
> POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.######.####
> Authorization: Basic /* some unique strings and numbers here */
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> grant_type=client_credentials
> ```

Sorry for my English, but I already tried to explain what i want clear as possible.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about these "some people", but you can do whatever the heck you want with Laravel, it imposes no restrictions. As long as PHP can do it, Laravel can do it.

Either search for a package that implements the API, e.g.

```
composer require <api-package>
```

e.g To use the Instagram API in PHP, may be try this package:

```
composer require cosenary/instagram
```

All dependencies are listen in `composer.json`.

If you can't find it, implementing an HTTP API package is easy using `php-curl`. (The `curl` from command line in `PHP`). Read the respective API documentation, and keep implementing each resource route for the API one by one.

The complete `curl` documentation for `PHP` can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer I really appreciate it!


[link](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) 


For this php-curl can i use that repo ?

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya I have updated the answer with a link to official docs. It will include installation. You can mark the answer and upvote if it satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Use guzzle, and perform your request to any webservice such below example:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://example.com/api/oauth/token', [
        'headers' = [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic your_token'
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

refer here http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html